# looping vertex removal in igraph and keeping the same layout coordinates

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to be able to iteratively remove vertices based on vertices attributes.  I'd like the output to look something like this:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_literal(1-+2, 2-+3, 3-+4, 4-+1, 5)

V(g)$year <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)

kk <- layout_with_kk(g)

kk <- norm_coords(kk, xmin=-1, xmax = 1, ymin=-1, ymax = 1)

par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(1,1,1,1))

# First plot
plot(g,
     vertex.label = V(g)$year,
     layout = kk*.5,
     frame = TRUE,
     main = "Original")

# Second plot
x <- as.numeric(which(V(g)$year <= 2000))

g2 <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$year <= 2000)

kk2 = kk[dput(x),]
#> c(1, 2)

plot(g2,
     vertex.label = V(g2)$year,
     layout = kk2*.5,
     frame = TRUE,
     main = "2000 and earlier")

# third plot
x <- as.numeric(which(V(g)$year <= 2001))

g3 <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$year <= 2001)

kk2 = kk[dput(x),]
#> c(1, 2, 3)

plot(g3,
     vertex.label = V(g3)$year,
     layout = kk2*.5,
     frame = TRUE,
     main = "2001 and earlier")

# fourth plot
x <- as.numeric(which(V(g)$year <= 2002))

g4 <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$year <= 2002)

kk2 = kk[dput(x),]
#> c(1, 2, 3, 4)

plot(g4,
     vertex.label = V(g4)$year,
     layout = kk2*.5,
     frame = TRUE,
     main = "2001 and earlier")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My actual data set is large, so I'd like to loop it so I don't have to write the code a million times. I took some inspiration from [here](http://estebanmoro.org/post/2015-12-21-temporal-networks-with-r-and-igraph-updated/)--and it gets me kind of close, but not close enough and I'm at the end of my abilities here.

```r
g <- graph_from_literal(1-+2, 2-+3, 3-+4, 4-+1, 5)

V(g)$year <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)

layout.old <- norm_coords(layout.kamada.kawai(g), xmin = -1, xmax = 1, ymin = -1, ymax = 1)

maxyr <- max(V(g)$year)

dev.off()
#> null device 
#>           1

par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(1,1,1,1))

for(yr in seq(2001, maxyr, 1)){
  gind <- induced_subgraph(g, V(g)$year <= yr)
  layout.new <- layout.kamada.kawai(g,coords=layout.old)
  plot(gind,
       vertex.label = V(gind)$year,
       layout = layout.new,
       frame = TRUE)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The output from this maintains the coordinates and seems to produce some of the iterations, but otherwise doesn't behave as I'd hoped (producing output like the non-looped examples).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something along these lines. You can "attach" the coordinates to the nodes and use them in a short custom plotting function.

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
g <- graph_from_literal(1-+2, 2-+3, 3-+4, 4-+1, 5)
V(g)$year <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)
xy <- norm_coords(
  layout_with_kk(g),
  xmin=-1, xmax = 1, ymin=-1, ymax = 1
)
V(g)$x <- xy[,1]
V(g)$y <- xy[,2]

myplot <- function(g, ...) {
  plot(g, layout=cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y), rescale = FALSE, ...)
}

layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2, byrow=TRUE))
myplot(g, main="Original")
myplot(induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[year <= 2000]), main="2000 and earlier")
myplot(induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[year <= 2001]), main="2001 and earlier")
myplot(induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[year <= 2002]), main="2002 and earlier")
```

[image]

```r
layout(1)
```

Incidentally, packages `tidygraph` and `ggraph` store vertex coordinates as vertex attributes in a largely similar way as above.

Comment: this solution totally sent me in the right direction. What was messing me up was how to deal with the coordinates. I ended up using `for()` to reiterate things, but your coordinate solution did the trick.